# Render Polygon Method (Documentation)

Tags: c#

I've written a method to render a polygon in `C#` using the `SharpDX` libraries and would like a review of my code's maintainability and the documentation around it. The method works fine as is, but I feel that perhaps the documentation could be improved, or that there could be simpler and more maintainable method of executing the algorithm.

```
/// <summary>
/// Render an n-sided polygon from a list of allowed polygons.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context2D">The 2D context used to render the polygon.</param>
/// <param name="polygon">The n-sided polygon to render.</param>
/// <param name="center">The central position of the polygon in 2D space</param>
/// <param name="radius">The radius of the polygon.</param>
/// <param name="rotation">The global rotation of the polygon (in degrees).</param>
public void RenderPolygon(DeviceContext context2D, PolygonType polygon, Vector2 center, float radius, float rotation) {
    float numberOfPoints = (float)polygon;
    Vector2? firstPoint = null, previousPoint = null, currentPoint = null;
    for (int n = 0; n < numberOfPoints; n++) {
        float theta = ((360.0f / numberOfPoints) * n + rotation) * (float)Math.PI / 180.0f;
        currentPoint = center + new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(theta), (float)Math.Sin(theta)) * radius;

        if (previousPoint != null && currentPoint != null)
            context2D.DrawLine((Vector2)previousPoint, (Vector2)currentPoint, brush);

        previousPoint = currentPoint;
        if (firstPoint == null)
            firstPoint = currentPoint;
    }

    if (firstPoint != null && currentPoint != null)
        context2D.DrawLine((Vector2)currentPoint, (Vector2)firstPoint, brush);
}
```

---

With regards to the `PolygonType` argument, this is an `enum` with `int` values for each type; for example:

```
public enum PolygonType {
    Trigon = 3,
    Tetragon = 4,
    Pentagon = 5
}
```

There are a total of 30 polygon types offered stopping at `Chiliagon` which has `1000` sides.

---

The things I am most interested in are:

- Ensuring documentation provides as much detail as possible (while remaining concise).
- Ensuring that the algorithm is easy to follow and maintain.

The one thing I don't currently like about the algorithm:

- Casting from `Vector2?` to `Vector2` seems redundant (though required in the current case).

Since `Vector2`'s default value is `0, 0`, I'm not sure I should use it and have chosen to use null; but since `Vector2` is not a nullable type, I have to cast back to the normal `Vector2` prior to using my variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most confusing thing in your code is names of arguments and variables and their types.

> ```
> DeviceContext context2D
> ```

Why not `deviceContext`?

> ```
> PolygonType polygon
> ```

It's not polygon (which is collection of points as I expect), it's polygon type, so name it `polygonType`

> ```
> float numberOfPoints = (float)polygon;
> ```

Why are you casting to `float`? Number of points can be non-integer? Also in my opinion it's not good to give another meanings to enum values except what they mean by their names. Your enum defines polygons types, not numbers of points. I recommend to create dictionary:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<PolygonType, int> NumberOfPoints =
    new Dictionary<PolygonType, int>
    {
        [PolygonType.Trigon] = 3,
        // ...
    };
```

and use it:

```
var numberOfPoints = NumberOfPoints[polygonType];
```

Why are you using for polygon types such strange names and not *Triangle* and *Square*?

If it's public API method, add arguments checking using appropriate exceptions (`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, `InvalidEnumArgumentException` and so on). All possible exceptions should be documented via `<exception>` tags.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback; the reason for `context2D` has been made redundant by making that particular parameter a field in the class, however since `DeviceContext` is the same in the 2D and 3D namespaces calling it `context2D` seems to be pretty common across the board. Casting to `float` was to prevent casting down the line as part of division; and in regards to the `PolygonType` names within the `enum` I used the mathematical names to add clarity since a square is not a diamond, but they are both tetragons.